# How to read Json data from Postman using Selenium

Tags: java, json, selenium

I have to open a Postman and pass Url using GET option.It will generate a Json data. which I have to read and compare with existing data.
So anyone can help me?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you are trying to comparing your data in a API response return as `JSON` format

This code might help you -

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class WebAPITest 
{

    public static String url1="http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1";        

    @Test
    public void getAPIRequest() throws Exception
    {
        try 
        {           
            URL url = new URL(url1);            
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");  
            if(conn.getResponseCode() != 200) 
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(" HTTP error code : "+ conn.getResponseCode());
            }   
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(url.openStream());
            String entireResponse = new String();       
            while (scan.hasNext())

                entireResponse += scan.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Response : " + entireResponse);

                scan.close();

                System.out.println("API response Code : " + conn.getResponseCode() +"\t" + conn.getResponseMessage());

                JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(entireResponse);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) 
            {

                String countryname = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                System.out.println("Country name  : " + countryname);

                JSONArray languages = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("languages");
                System.out.print("Country languages : ");
                for(int j=0;j<languages.length();j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(languages.get(j) +"  ");
                }
                System.out.println("");
                String capital = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("capital");
                System.out.println("Country Capital  : " + capital);
            }

            conn.disconnect();

            } 

            catch (MalformedURLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
    }

}
```